# "[unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server] Unable to connect to data source"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ruby-on-rails-4, unixodbc

When my app starts I get an ODBC Error:

```
  ODBC::Error
    S1000 (0) [unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect to data source
    Rails.root: /var/www/html/TEST_APP
```

I'm using Linux RHEL5 + apache with passenger + MSSQL Server 2008.

file **database.yml**:

```
development:
adapter: sqlserver
dsn: MSSQL
host: ip_address
port: 1433
mode: odbc
database: mydatabasename
username: myusername
password: mypassword
```

file **freetds.conf**:

```
  [MSSQL]
    host = ip_address
    port = 1433
    tds version = 8.0
    client charset = UTF-8
```

file **odbc.ini**:

```
  [MSSQL]
    Driver=MSSQL
    Description=ODBC connection via FreeTDS
    Servername=MSSQL
    Port=1433
    Database=mydatabasename
    Username=myusername
    Password=mypassword
```

file **odbc.ini**:

```
 [MSSQL]
    Description     = for mssql
    Driver          = /usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so
    Setup           = /usr/lib64/libtdsS.so
    FileUsage       = 1
```

isql works:

```
 # isql -v MSSQL myusername mypassword
    +---------------------------------------+
    | Connected!                            |
    |                                       |
    | sql-statement                         |
    | help [tablename]                      |
    | quit                                  |
    |                                       |
    +---------------------------------------+
    SQL>
```

tsql also works:

```
   # tsql -S MSSQL -U myusername -P mypassword
    locale is "en_US.UTF-8"
    locale charset is "UTF-8"
    using default charset "UTF-8"
    1>
```

My gemlist:

```
gem 'rails', '4.1.8'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc
gem 'spring',        group: :development

gem 'tiny_tds'
gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter', '4.1.0'
gem 'dbd-odbc'
gem 'dbi'
gem 'ruby-odbc'
```

Log:

```
  ODBC::Error (S1000 (0) [unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect to data source):
  activerecord-sqlserver-adapter (4.1.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver_adapter.rb:343:in `initialize'
  activerecord-sqlserver-adapter (4.1.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver_adapter.rb:343:in `connect'
  activerecord-sqlserver-adapter (4.1.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver_adapter.rb:343:in `odbc_connect'
  activerecord-sqlserver-adapter (4.1.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver_adapter.rb:278:in `connect'
  activerecord-sqlserver-adapter (4.1.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver_adapter.rb:62:in `initialize'
  activerecord-sqlserver-adapter (4.1.0) lib/active_record/sqlserver_base.rb:17:in `new'
  activerecord-sqlserver-adapter (4.1.0) lib/active_record/sqlserver_base.rb:17:in `sqlserver_connection'
  activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:435:in `new_connection'
  activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:445:in `checkout_new_connection'
  activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:416:in `acquire_connection'
  activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:351:in `block in checkout'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
  activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:350:in `checkout'
  activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:265:in `block in connection'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
  activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:264:in `connection'
  activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:541:in `retrieve_connection'
  activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'
  activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connection'
  activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:51:in `restore_query_cache_settings'
  activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:43:in `rescue in call'
  activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:32:in `call'
  activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in `call'
  activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/migration.rb:380:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:84:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
  passenger (5.0.6) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:85:in `process_request'
  passenger (5.0.6) lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:149:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
  passenger (5.0.6) lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:110:in `main_loop'
  passenger (5.0.6) lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:414:in `block (3 levels) in start_threads'
  passenger (5.0.6) lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:111:in `block in create_thread_and_abort_on_exception'


  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (0.7ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (1.6ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.2ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (22.6ms)
```

`rake db:migrate` works and creates table in mydatabase.
I see this error in website browser when I'm trying to see website.
Do you have any idea where the problem is?

Comment: Your DB is not up, you are passing the wrong credentials, or the box that it's on is not reachable

Comment: DB is up and is working. I can run `rake db:migrate` from my command line, application creates table **schema_migrations** then.

Comment: I can also run:
`# rails console`  
Loading development environment (Rails 4.1.8)  
`2.1.5 :001 > client = TinyTds::Client.new username: 'myusername',
password: 'mypassword', host: 'ip_address', port: '1433'`  
 => #<TinyTds::Client:0x00000020dc71c8 @query_options={:as=>:hash,
:symbolize_keys=>false, :cache_rows=>true, :timezone=>:local,
:empty_sets=>true}>  
`2.1.5 :002 > client.active?`  
 => true

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. I had to change Linux settings:

```
httpd_can_network_connect_db --> off
```

to:

```
httpd_can_network_connect_db --> on
```